# Alternatives for US visa interview in London for disabled person?

Tags: usa, visa, uk-citizens, medical

My Husband and I are going to try and relocate to the USA.  He is British I am American.  I will be sending in the petition soon to start the process of obtaining the Visa for him to relocate.  I know that at sometime he would have to go to London for a medical and then a face to face interview.  The problem is he is disabled with MS and in a wheelchair that requires a modified vehicle to travel in and has a hard time traveling anyway. He does not drive.

My question: is there an alternate site in Wales or what other alternate arrangements can be made for a disabled person to get the medical and have a face to face interview if required?

Comment: http://www.uscis.gov/tools/requesting-accommodations-disabilities

Comment: @mkennedy that only applies in the US.  Outside the US, one has to ask the state department (and, more specifically, the relevant US consulate) about available accommodations.

Answer (score 3):

The USCIS [website](http://www.uscis.gov/tools/requesting-accommodations-disabilities) that I posted as a comment is specifically for USCIS in the US.

I was not able to find any information on the US Embassy in London's website about accommodations for disabilities. However, because this is a BIG thing in the US, I would expect that some accommodations would be made. The USCIS webpage (link above) mentions a form I-648 but that form is to be used if you are seeking a exception to the English or civics exams.

A big issue could be the [medical examination](http://photos.state.gov/libraries/unitedkingdom/164203/cons-visa/iv018a_medical.pdf). I managed to pull up an information sheet about it and supposedly there is only a single practice, with two offices in London, that are approved to perform immigrant visa examinations.

I would contact the London Embassy first, and if they're unwilling to do anything, call the main USCIS National Customer Service Center (NCSC) at 1-800-375-5283.